# Flutter Error - "Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]' Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm facing this issue while showing data from Firestore on my Flutter App

Error:

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: []("quizImgUrl")
Found: []() => Map<String, dynamic>
```

[image]

My code:

```
  Widget QuizList() {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: quizStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.data == null
              ? Container()
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    snapshot.data.documents
                        .map((doc) => new ListTile(
                            title: new Text(doc["quizTitle"]),
                            subtitle: new Text(doc["quizImgUrl"].toString())))
                        .toList();
                    return QuizTile(
                      imgUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['quizImgUrl'],
                      desc: snapshot
                          .data.documents[index].data['quizDescription'],
                      title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['quizTitle'],
                    );
                  });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Database code:

```
  Future<void> addQuestionData(Map questionData, String quizId) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Quiz")
        .doc(quizId)
        .collection("QNA")
        .add(questionData)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

**[Full code](https://github.com/swarupbhanjachowdhury/agriglance-flutter)**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closure call with mismatched arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309170/closure-call-with-mismatched-arguments-function-error-is-being-shown-in-fl/64309300#64309300)

Comment: Has the answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to call data() method first. Then you can get the value of the indexed item. It should be like this:

```
      return QuizTile(
                  imgUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data()["quizImgUrl"],
                  desc: snapshot
                      .data.documents[index].data()["quizDescription"],
                  title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data()["quizTitle"],
                );
```